# How to get T-SQL Raiserror custom parameters from SQLException?

Tags: .net, sqlexception, raiseerror

I have a database table trigger that can `RAISERROR` at multiple point of the code.
I know that we can add some custom arguments along with the `RAISERROR` calls (I think that those parameters are mainly for setting a custom error message).

All of this is fine.

On the *.Net* part of the code *(C# for me)*, when I catch the related error, everything is almost fine, I can get it's custom message, state, severity...

... but I'm still struggling to get back my custom parameters from this C# `SqlException` object and I failed to find information after a long research.

My questions are :

1. Is it possible to recover those parameters directly from the `SqlException`? *(without having to parse the generated error message)*
2. If possible, how to get them ? Where are they hidding inside the exception object?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found a solution.

I'm now forgetting to pass custom parameters through the T-Sql `Raiserror` and I directly get the entity on error and all its values thanks to the parent exception of type `DbUpdateException` *(in my case)* which contains an `Entries` collection with my full entity on error.

I just need to cast that generic type into my real entity model and I'm good to go.

Thanks.